# make something after vuex state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

‍‍
I Have these issue, I have read a lot about these issues but I do not understand why it is not working. I have two components, one send data to array in vuex, but I want to fire something when these data has change.

these is my component of simple list of values as a checkbox input:

```
<div
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.label"
        class="text-white flex align-items-center mr-3 mb-2 md:mb-0"
      >
        <input
          @click="getSelectedLocations()"
          v-model="item.value"
          type="checkbox"
          name="option"
          class="
            h-7
            w-7
            bg-white
            text-indigo-600
            focus:ring-indigo-500
            rounded-sm
            m-1
            border-white
          "
        />
        <p class="mt-1 text-xl">{{ item.label }}</p>
      </div>

///theMethod

methods: {
    getSelectedLocations() {
      this.$store.commit("selectedLocationsByUser", this.items);
    },
  },
```

My data send to the other component right , but I need to know when the state change:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(["selectedLocations"]),
    ...mapGetters(["userProfile"]),
  },
  watch: {
    selectedLocations(nv, ov) {
      console.log(nv);
      console.log("old:", ov);
    },
  },
```

My Vuex

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    selectedLocations: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    selectedLocationsByUser(state, payload) {
      state.selectedLocations = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
  getters: {},
```

The console shows me 1 change, but when I select again the values on the checkbox component it doesn't fire the watch function. any idea what is wrong? ‍

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Vuex snippet that handles this mutation?

Comment: shure, @anatolhiman, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the state is an array you need to add `deep:true` option to the watcher, and bind the inputs directly to the state :

```
computed: {
  
    ...mapGetters(["userProfile"]),

   selectedLocations:{
        get(){ return this.$store.stateselectedLocations},
        set(val){
           this.$store.commit("selectedLocationsByUser", val);
        } 

   }
  },
  watch: {
  selectedLocations:{
     handler(nv, ov) {
       console.log(nv);
       console.log("old:", ov);
     },
     deep:true
    }
  },
```

in template :

```
<input    v-model="selectedLocations" :value="item.value"
          type="checkbox"
          name="option"
...
```